# How do I check if I have received all the data from a get-request in jest & react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, axios, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

**My Problem**
I want to write a test (with react-testing-library and jest) to verify that my get-request is receiving a list of json-objects (with length > 400).
The code for this is presented below.
The problem is that I  am getting the error message: "Timed out in waitFor".
What am I doing wrong?, I am greatful for any help and/or guidance.

```
import React {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

const TestComp = () => {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
    Axios.get("/../someURL").then((res) => {
        setData(res.data);
    })
});

return (
    <table>
        {state.data.map(d => (
            <tr>
                <th>
                    {data.req_id}
                </th>
            </tr>
        ))}
    </table>
  );
};
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {render, screen, waitFor} from '@testing-library/react';
import TestComp from "./../TestComp";

test("test", async () => {
    render(<TestComp/>);
    await waitFor(async() => {
        const receivedRows = await screen.findAllByRole("row"); 
        const nrOfReceivedRows = receivedRows.length;
        expect(nrOfReceivedRows > 400).toBeTruthy();
        // I have also tried expect(nrOfReceivedRows).toBeGreaterThan(400);
    });
})
```

Comment: Are you making a _real request_ in a test for TestComp and, if so, why?

Comment: Yes exactly, it is a real request, I am new to testing, and I thought that making a real request would be smart, because then I can know (whenever I would run the test) whether it is the back-end that fails or the front-end.

Comment: @jonrsharpe , perhaps I am thinking about this in the wrong way?

Comment: I would say so, because right now the test is failing and you can't tell if it's the back-end or the front-end where the problem is. Also real network requests are generally orders of magnitude slower than you're looking for unit-level tests to be. I would recommend having E2E tests that check the whole thing works together, but at this level you should probably think about network-level mocking (e.g. `msw`) or having a facade around Axios you can mock out yourself. I've written about testing React apps in this way on my blog: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2021/Apr/10/js-tdd-api.html

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some issues:

1. `<tr>` cannot appear as a child of `<table>`. Add a `<tbody>`, `<thead>` or `<tfoot>` to your code to match the DOM tree generated by the browser.
2. `findBy` methods are a combination of `getBy` queries and `waitFor`. They accept the `waitFor` options as the last argument (e.g. `await screen.findByText('text', queryOptions, waitForOptions)`). You don't need to use `waitFor` and `findBy` query together. See [findBy Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#findby-queries)
3. For unit testing, you should **NOT** call the real external service such as (API call, db query etc...). These services with side effects should be mocked or stub. This way your tests can be run in an isolated environment, without relying on external real services. The test that calls the real service should be E2E test.

In summary, a unit test example, use `jest.spyOn()` to mock `axios.get` method and its resolved/rejected value.

`TestComp.jsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

export const TestComp = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('/../someURL').then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      setData(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {data.map((d) => (
          <tr key={d.req_id}>
            <th>{d.req_id}</th>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

`TestComp.test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { TestComp } from './TestComp';

test('test', async () => {
  const getSpy = jest.spyOn(Axios, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce({
    data: Array(401)
      .fill()
      .map((d, idx) => ({ req_id: idx })),
  });
  render(<TestComp />);
  const receivedRows = await screen.findAllByRole('row');
  expect(receivedRows.length > 400).toBeTruthy();
  getSpy.mockRestore();
});
```

test result:

```
  console.log
    {
      data: [
        { req_id: 0 },  { req_id: 1 },  { req_id: 2 },  { req_id: 3 },
        { req_id: 4 },  { req_id: 5 },  { req_id: 6 },  { req_id: 7 },
        { req_id: 8 },  { req_id: 9 },  { req_id: 10 }, { req_id: 11 },
        { req_id: 12 }, { req_id: 13 }, { req_id: 14 }, { req_id: 15 },
        { req_id: 16 }, { req_id: 17 }, { req_id: 18 }, { req_id: 19 },
        { req_id: 20 }, { req_id: 21 }, { req_id: 22 }, { req_id: 23 },
        { req_id: 24 }, { req_id: 25 }, { req_id: 26 }, { req_id: 27 },
        { req_id: 28 }, { req_id: 29 }, { req_id: 30 }, { req_id: 31 },
        { req_id: 32 }, { req_id: 33 }, { req_id: 34 }, { req_id: 35 },
        { req_id: 36 }, { req_id: 37 }, { req_id: 38 }, { req_id: 39 },
        { req_id: 40 }, { req_id: 41 }, { req_id: 42 }, { req_id: 43 },
        { req_id: 44 }, { req_id: 45 }, { req_id: 46 }, { req_id: 47 },
        { req_id: 48 }, { req_id: 49 }, { req_id: 50 }, { req_id: 51 },
        { req_id: 52 }, { req_id: 53 }, { req_id: 54 }, { req_id: 55 },
        { req_id: 56 }, { req_id: 57 }, { req_id: 58 }, { req_id: 59 },
        { req_id: 60 }, { req_id: 61 }, { req_id: 62 }, { req_id: 63 },
        { req_id: 64 }, { req_id: 65 }, { req_id: 66 }, { req_id: 67 },
        { req_id: 68 }, { req_id: 69 }, { req_id: 70 }, { req_id: 71 },
        { req_id: 72 }, { req_id: 73 }, { req_id: 74 }, { req_id: 75 },
        { req_id: 76 }, { req_id: 77 }, { req_id: 78 }, { req_id: 79 },
        { req_id: 80 }, { req_id: 81 }, { req_id: 82 }, { req_id: 83 },
        { req_id: 84 }, { req_id: 85 }, { req_id: 86 }, { req_id: 87 },
        { req_id: 88 }, { req_id: 89 }, { req_id: 90 }, { req_id: 91 },
        { req_id: 92 }, { req_id: 93 }, { req_id: 94 }, { req_id: 95 },
        { req_id: 96 }, { req_id: 97 }, { req_id: 98 }, { req_id: 99 },
        ... 301 more items
      ]
    }

      at examples/68312820/TestComp.jsx:8:15

 PASS  examples/68312820/TestComp.test.jsx (9.507 s)
  ✓ test (799 ms)

--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File          | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 TestComp.jsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.181 s
```